# MVC Model - Display annotation href

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a model with the following property :

```
[Display(Name = @"<a href=""Home/LegalInformation"">Accept</a>")]
public bool Accept { get; set; }
```

My issue is that the hyperlink created is pointing to the following path which is not correct :

```
http://localhost:3452/Account/Home/LegalInformation
```

The correct path should be :

```
http://localhost:3452/Home/LegalInformation
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: why would you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 [Display(Name = @"<a href=""/Home/LegalInformation"">Accept</a>")]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was missing that slash.